# Заблокировать вкладку tabControl1

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на кнопку сделать невозможным переход на другую вкладку.

### tabControl1.Enabled = false; Внезапно блокирует текущую вкладку.

Относительно оптимальный вариант костылей.

```
static TabPage tabCode;
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tabCode == null) // проверяем если ли что-то в переменной
        {
            tabCode = tabControl1.TabPages[0]; // запоминаем вкладку которую хотим скрыть
            tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(0); // удаляем ее из коллекции
        }
        else {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0,tabCode); // если в массиве что-то есть то добавляем в начало коллекции
        }
        return;
}
```

Comment: Так дизейблить нужно определенные `tabPage`, а не весь `tabControl`

Comment: TabPages не имеет метода Enabled

Comment: Попробуйте перехватить событие

Comment: @KordDEM да там спрятанное свойство просто, попробуйте.

Comment: @yolosora, tabControl1.TabPages.Enabled, не содержит определение.

Comment: @KordDEM попробуйте тогда к `Control` прикастить

Comment: @Tivyram, объявить переменную и проверять при переключении вкладки? Не костыль?

Comment: @yolosora, Снова мимо) Там 2 метода и это не то)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418006/how-can-i-disable-a-tab-inside-a-tabcontrol

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/de-DE/985b41c3-a1de-4744-8875-63262d4c2718/tabcontrol-disableenable-tab-page?forum=winforms

Answer (score 1):

## перевод. [источник: msdn.microsoft.com/Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/de-DE/985b41c3-a1de-4744-8875-63262d4c2718/tabcontrol-disableenable-tab-page?forum=winforms)

Вы не можете отключить вкладку как таковую, но вы можете имитировать это поведение.

Вы можете сделать что-то вроде следующего:

1. Добавьте TabControl с 2 страницами.
2. Установите DrawMode в OwnerDrawFixed.
3. Присоедините событие TabControl.Selecting к tabControl1_Selecting
4. Присоедините событие TabControl.DrawItem к tabControl1_DrawItem
5. Затем скопируйте следующий код в вашей формы (вам придется немного изменить ее)

---

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  tabPage2.Enabled = false;

}
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
  if (!e.TabPage.Enabled)
  {
  e.Cancel = true;
  }
}

private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
  TabPage page = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

  if (!page.Enabled)
  {
  using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.GrayText))
  {
    e.Graphics.DrawString(page.Text, page.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
  }
  }
  else
  {
  using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(page.ForeColor))
  {
    e.Graphics.DrawString(page.Text, page.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
  }
  }
}
```

В основном то, что вы делаете - это рисуете свои собственные вкладки. Вы отключаете TabPage в своем конструкторе - имейте в виду, что TabPage.Enabled не отображается в дизайнере или intellisense, но он существует.

Затем при срабатывании события `Selecting` вы прерываете фокус отключенной страницы. В DrawItem вы сами рисуете вкладки, чтобы вы могли имитировать вкладку «отключено».

Это не полное решение, но вам это поможет.

HTH

David